# Undefined method [] in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, undefined

I am running Ruby 2.2.2 on Windows 7 Professional. I am trying to make a menu program that stores multiple menus in one array. I thought that I had succeeded, but I get the error message

```
Menu.rb:7:in 'block in load':undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here is my code:

```
#-Functions-#
def load(page)
    data = [["menu","Menu",[["obj1","Object 1",false],["exit","Exit",true]]],["obj1","Object 1",[["menu","Back",false],["exit","Exit",true]]],["exit","Exit",false]]
    itemNum = 0
    data.each do
        pageData = data[itemNum]
        if pageData[0] == page      #ErrorLine
            if pageData[2] == false
                send(page)
            else
                system "cls"
                puts
                puts " #{pageData[1]}"
                puts
                itemNum = 1
                pageData[2].each do
                    puts
                    puts "  #{itemNum}. #{pageData[2][itemNum-1][1]}"
                    itemNum += 1
                end
                puts
                puts
                print " Choice: "
                choice = gets.chomp.to_i
                load(pageData[choice-1][0])
            end
        end
        itemNum +=1
    end
end
def exit
    exit
end

#-Program-#
load("menu")
```

Comment: Hint: somewhere in your code, `itemNum` becomes a number bigger than `3`.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data array is set up with 3 elements, however if you log your program, 
try this at the end of your each loop

```
data.each do
  ...
  itemNum +=1
  puts "itemNum is now #{itemNum}"
end
```

Run it and you will see that at some point "itemNum is now 4". 
Hence at your line 7 pageData is nil, as data[4] element doesnt exist.

Comment: This wasn't really an answer, but it lead me in the right direction! I was using itemNum inside the writing part, so I made a new variable called pageNum and used that in the data.each!